# How to Import github project based on commit history

Tags: java, eclipse, git, github

I have project in github. I have committed a irrelevant code in repo. So due to this my app is not working. So i need to import the project without the last two commits. How is this possible?

I am using eclipse IDE and java language code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers. I have found the answer in IDE iteslf.

Right click the project -> Team -> Show in History -> (A small window will open, it will have all the commits with the caption) -> Again right click on the commit that you need to import -> Click Checkout

Answer (score 0):

You need to grab the repo and reset back 2 commits. The best way to do this is to checkout the repo locally:

```
git clone https://github.com/user/proj.git
```

and enter the repo.

```
git reset --hard HEAD~2
```

and

```
git push origin master --fast-forward
```

The last line **only** if you want to remove the commits.

Comment: Did you mean `clone` instead of `checkout`? I don't think you can `checkout` a url.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming that you committed the last two commits locally. Then you want to do a hard reset to go 2 commits back. You can make a backup branch of the two commits in case you still want them later:

```bash
# Make backup branch
git branch backup

# Do a hard reset of the current branch
git reset --hard head~2
```